# Select with associated documents in OrientDB

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb, document-database

How do I query the DB and get an AttendanceReport with all association data (LeaderAttending and PersonAttending)? Not just RID's that I do with a regular `select from AttendanceReport`.

Or should I use [links](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Relationships.html) for this kind of data?

I am a newbie to OrientDB, graph and document databases.

```
create class Person extends V
create class Leader extends Person
create class AttendanceReport extends V
create class HasLeader extends E
create class LeaderAttending extends E
create class PersonAttending extends E

create property Person.name string
create property AttendanceReport.meetingDate datetime

create vertex Person set name='Billy'
create vertex Person set name='Jane'
create vertex Leader set name='Boss'
create vertex AttendanceReport set meetingDate='2015-09-25 11:00:00'

create edge HasLeader from (select from Person where name='Billy') to (select from Leader where name='Boss')

create edge HasLeader from (select from Person where name='Jane') to (select from Leader where name='Boss')

create edge LeaderAttending from (select from AttendanceReport limit 1) to (select from Leader where name='Boss')

create edge PersonAttending from (select from AttendanceReport limit 1) to (select from Person where name='Jane')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this query

```
select in.name,out.meetingDate from (select expand(outE('LeaderAttending','PersonAttending')) from AttendanceReport  )
```